# How can I blend two colours to a mix of them in OpenGL?

Tags: opengl

I'm rendering both a blue and a red line (in the context of an anaglyph). When the red line and blue line overlap I want a purple color to be rendered instead of the line in front.

I am using OpenGL. Some of the code I have tried so far is this:

```
glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_DST_ALPHA);
```

This causes the overlap to render *white*, and the line appears as follows:
[image]

I thought maybe using an RGB scale factor on top of this blend would be the right thing to do.

So I tried using the `glBlendFuncSeparate` which takes parameters:

1. Source Factor RGB
2. Destination Factor RGB
3. Source Factor Alpha
4. Destination Factor Alpha

I could not find parameters which made this work for me.

I also attempted using `glBlendEquation` with an additive equation, but didn't notice any success in that method.

How do I produce a function which successfully blends the two lines into a purple color?

Edit:

I've noticed that `glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_DST_ALPHA)` does perform some blending to produce intermediate colors (the actual lines are just nonsensical here, it was just to display some blending).
[image]

Comment: why you can't do it with shader?

Comment: You seem to be blending red with cyan. That generally won't make purple.

Comment: @JasonD I understand, which is why I was looking for a scale factor blend method. I was talking to someone more experienced with anaglyphs than I, and he said that the purple blend was good for tricking the eye.

Comment: @SAKrisT Maybe I should... How do I go about it?

Comment: Which seems strange to me because in anaglyph images, the overlapping regions tend to be grey. I would recommend posting a picture of the kind of blending you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @louisdeb it's not so simple explain in comets if you not familiar with it. So, firstly just start read about shaders and play around with them.

Answer (score 2):

> I'm rendering both a blue and a red line (in the context of an anaglyph)

Not the answer you expect, but the answer you need: The usual approach to render anaglyph images in OpenGL *is not* to use blending. Blending is hard enough to get right, you don't want to mess things up further with the anaglyph part.

There are two commonly used methods:

- Rendering each view into a FBO attached texture and combining them in a postprocessing step.
- using `glColorMask` to select the active color channels for each rendering step.

I think for now you're good with the color mask method: Do it as following:

```
display:
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
    glViewport(…)

    # prepare left view
    setup_left_view_projection()
    glColorMask(1,0,0, 1); # red is commonly used for the left eye

    draw_scene()

    glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT) # clear the depth buffer (and just the depth buffer!)

    # prepare right view
    setup_right_view_projection()
    glColorMask(0,1,1, 1); # cyan is commonly used for the right eye

    draw_scene()
```

Comment: Yeah, I've actually got the anaglyph rendering by calculating it manually, which works fine for me. However I was talking to a peer who had experience in anaglyphs and he said that blending the two to a purple would trick the eye more effectively.

Answer (score 1):

The typical blend function is `glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);`; note that the final color changes according to the draw order.

Blend functions are not so obvious, so a graphical representation sometimes is better; check out for example [this](http://www.zeuscmd.com/tutorials/opengles/19-blending.php) site.

Comment: That site has [this image](http://www.zeuscmd.com/tutorials/opengles/images/19-Blending04.jpg) which appears to be the blending method I want, however it results in no blending at all.

Comment: The function you gave me also didn't result in a blend. I think the problem arising is that they don't always overlap when I want them to blend. They just appear to overlap. (As in they overlap in projection not physically)

Comment: The image you've highlighted shows blending blue and red to get purple. You're not blending blue and red, you're blending cyan and red.

Comment: @louisdeb do your lines colors have alpha component < 1 ? The cyan line should have (0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.5f)

Comment: @JasonD Sorry, cyan is correct. Wasn't being tight enough on my choice of words.

Comment: @Zac No, currently the lines have alpha component of 1. I'll change this and try it out. Should my red also have alpha < 1?

Comment: @louisdeb in order to use this blend function you must set the alpha component <1 of the overlapped line, the second you are drawing.